# How does an undelete vote work?

Tags: discussion, support

I guess we've all suffered the irritation of a question being deleted by the author, right at the point you were about to hit the Post button on an answer you'd just worked on.

Having had that just happen [not for the first time] on this question - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/109464/how-are-the-crew-of-just-for-laughs-gags-not-recognized - I voted to undelete it.

Does that now go to the review queue to be voted on?

If it does, I don't see a great chance for it to gain a lot of sympathy. It's not really a great question, but it has a validity for any of those hidden camera shows in how they do achieve a lot of the structure. It could easily be genericised a little to not apply to only that one show… and then I can paste my answer back into it ;)

Comment: Not really.

Posts you have voted to undelete do not go to any review queue. However, one can take a look at [this tool](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tools) accessible to users with > 10k reputation. But they should know about this to get there.

Comment: @AJ9 - Hmm… that's a bit of a failing. I know of that page, though I hardly ever look at it - which makes me think few others would either [based on a sample size of one, I know], but that essentially just leaves it in limbo.

Comment: Undeleting a post is next to impossible through the normal means. Your best bet is to ask on meta or in chat for others to undelete it... preferably with why you think it should be undeleted. The Tools page is just under used and not very accessible and even then it's on a max of 30 days before it's lost to everything but SEDE and blindly stumbling across it... which of course is next to impossible for deleted posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by comments and a scouring of the global Meta on similar subjects, I ought to just give this up as a lost cause.

There is no structure in place to revive a deleted post and the post in question wasn't really worth the effort of trying to call in favours from chat.

I think this is a broken structure, but I don't think it worth the effort of pursuing in this particular case.